# Php7 practices regarding Throwable errors

Tags: magento, php-7

Long story short is that we've recently switched from php 5.6 to php 7. Although the application (a Magento 1.9 based app) seems to work accordingly after the switch, we have some shell scripts which somehow/sometimes die all of the sudden without knowing why:

```
Mage::log("doing something", null, 'custom.log', true); <- logged, see it
doSomething(); <- perfroms a service call, which looks like it's done properly
Mage::log("something done", null, 'custom.log', true); <- not logged
```

The problem in the above is that we have absolutely no error, warning, etc. so we cannot determine what happens. Since the changing of error handling in Php7, I assume that an error occurs (which previously was being logged in /var/log/...) and now is thrown as an Error exception, which based on Php7 specifications is not caught by a classic catch(Exception $e){} block. So my main questions regarding this whole situation is:

When switching from Php5.X to Php7, wouldn't it be a good practice to change the catch(Exception $e) with catch(Throwable $e) as Throwable covers both Excptions and new Errors? Otherwise, if I'm correct, one should add multiple "catch (Error $e)" blocks inside the code where this could occur in order to catch these error now.

Comment: You could indeed do `catch (Throwable $e)`. But given the sort of circumstances where an `Error` might be thrown, I might be wary of this. I think it's unlikely to come up unless there's a bug in your code.